# error in json python parsing

Tags: python, json, parsing, dictionary

I've loaded a JSON file but I'm not able to parse it in order to update or insert values.

The JSON structure is similar to this one:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
            "id": "node1",
            "x": 21.0,
            "y": 8.0
        },
        {
            "id": "node5",
            "x": 3.0,
            "y": 5.0
        }
    ]
}
```

While my python code to retrieve a node is similar to this:

```
jsonData = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
print jsonData['nodes']['id'] == 'node5'
```

The error I get is "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str".

How can I retrieve a node and how can I update it?

Comment: By the way, the JSON you have is broken, the third from last line has a `,` after the `}` which shouldn't be there.

Comment: Thank you, it's my fault but fortunally it's only a bad copy and paste, the original JSON is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JSON, `nodes` is a list of objects, so you can't try to access elements inside it using a string like you are doing with `'id'`.

Instead, you can iterate over it:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

for item in jsonData['nodes']:
    print item['id'], item['x'], item['y']
```

[Edit]
To address your comment:

```
with open('data.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)

jsonData['nodes'] = {e['id']: e for e in jsonData['nodes']}
jsonData['nodes']['node5']['z'] = 12
```

Comment: thank you Joseph but in this way how can I add a new value to an old node? (Say... I need to add "z"= 12 in the node with id = 'node5'.)

Comment: If you don't have any control over the JSON you're reading in, you have two options: one, iterate over all of `json['nodes']` and inside the loop, check if the current element is the one you want to modify. Or, better yet, just turn `jsonData['nodes']` into a dict itself based on its contents, e.g `jsonData['nodes'] = {e['id']: e for e in jsonData['nodes']}`

Answer (score 0):

This snippet adds a a new value (z=12) to an old node and updates the existing node y

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

jsonData = defaultdict(list)
with open('c:/temp/data.json', 'r') as f:
    jsonData = json.load(f)
for item in jsonData['nodes']:
    if  item['id']=='node5':
       item['y'] = 5
       item['z'] = 12
```